# Why didn't the USA move to the left after WWII?

Tags: united-states, world-war-two

After the second world war, and after the full impact of what the Nazis had done became clear, it seems like international politics moved to the left: in the east and far-east, support for communist movements rapidly rose; in the west, Socialist, Labour, and Trade-Unionist parties saw a sudden surge in support. The largest swing in UK electoral history, for example, was to the Labour party in the 1945 general election.

The US doesn't seem to have experienced this. Instead, if anything, it lurched to the right.

The Nazis are and were demonised as much in the US as in any of the other 2nd world war allies. Why didn't they experience the same political shift away from that direction as most other involved countries did.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36648/discussion-on-question-by-user984119-why-didnt-the-usa-move-to-the-left-after-w).

Comment: Please substantiate the claim that the USA did not move to the left after WWII. How are you measuring that? Is there any research that substantiates the claim that the USA moved to the right?

Comment: Given that red baiting was common in the 1920's and 1930's, and the Labor Movement continued in significance and strength in the three decades after WW II, your question appears to be based on a false premise.

Comment: I read somewhere that from the perspective of today the regime then would look left.

Comment: Poland definitely moved 300km to the left after World War II :p

Comment: This question is full with bias. The USA moved to the right? That's an assumption you have to proof. Good luck with that!

Comment: @Jos - Are you from an alternate timeline where McCarthyism and post-WW2-era capitalism never happened?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

It's probably too simplistic to say "the rest of the world jumped to the Left". That's not really the case. It's also pretty simplistic to say the U.S. "lurched to the right" - what does this mean in practical terms? The right wing/left wing paradigm is in of itself a simplistic paradigm that often obfuscates more than it illuminates. It also ignores the domestic political contexts in these nations that supposedly jumped to the left. I'm sure people had their own reasons for their voting intentions.

What we can say is that there are a couple of reasons why the Americans have traditionally favoured liberal capitalistic politics.

1. Cultural: The Americans were *already* pretty capitalistic; this was embodied in their early history as a nation and the laissez-faire period of the late 1800s & their frontier culture.
2. Strategic competition with Russia: The threat of the Soviet invasion of Western Europe would have represented a strategic imperative to refute the political ideology of socialism. This would also have been exacerbated by Mao's success in the Chinese civil war.
3. Labour market forces: The United States has always been a capitalistic country and the more powerful commercial entities would have considered it in their interests to use the threat of communism to degrade the threat of militant unionism.
4. Humans rights abuses: The abuses committed under Stalin and earlier during the Russian civil war would probably have been somewhat known to at least some in the American electorate.
5. Consumerism: was a wild success in the the 50s period and would have presented an excellent ideological alternative to the austerity of socialism. It was in fact, superior. Simply judging by the results of the two systems, the American liberal capitalism *was* superior to the Russian socialist system.
6. Economics: The massive mobilisation of American industry for WW2 created an industrial behemoth of the U.S. The Great Depression would be a fading memory by this time and the ideals of the American dream - individual prosperity created a new norm and new aspirations for the individual American.

In short there was not a single root cause for this but a number of existing and emerging factors that would have contributed to voter intentions. But did the United States really lurch to the right? What is "right" in this context? By what yardstick do we measure "rightness"? This is the problem with the right-wing left-wing paradigm - it doesn't explain a lot and tends to obfuscate more complicated political realities.

Comment: Reasonably good. You might note how the distinction between the *fiscal* and *social* life-right splits complicates analysis, and differs from Europe (and perhaps Canada) to the United States.

Comment: Left-Right paradigm is awful. Economic systems are often distinct from political. Fascism and Communisms are extremely similar politically (and economically) in their statist bent (concentrating political power and economic power in the hands of the state). The US moved the farthest from those paradigms post-war continuing to build individual freedoms (both economically and politically) into its political system.

Comment: About point 4 - while undeniable now, were the abuses actually widely known during the period in question? Wiki (yes, I know, can't even be called a "source") seems to indicate that light was shed mostly after Stalins death, so at least a decade after WW2.

Comment: Good answer.  It wouldn't hurt to also note revulsion to the racism and eugenics of Nazi Germany helped prepare America to reject both (regardless of where someone chooses to put them on a "left"-"right" spectrum).

Comment: @maple_shaft the CCCP was great in industrializing. #5 talks about the wealth of the individual. The US roughly started where the CCCP ended up in terms of technology available to the common household (Started at the eve of the Russian Revolution). The US was just much better at getting the (WWII and cold) war time advances into every living room - while the CCCP had tremendous success in industrializing (Electricity, Farm machines, Rail transport, ...)  Whether the one kind of achievement is better than the other is a judgment I'm not willing to make

Comment: @Ordous 0 I'm reasonably certain that emigres post 1917 would've communicated at least of what had occurred during the revolution and the civil war. Whilst the full extent of Stalins atrocities may not have been known, the colour and the shape would've been - for example the Nazis announced the Katyn massacre in 43/44 I believe.

Comment: @maple_shaft: That's not entirely true. If you read The Gulag archipelago and other contemporary sources, Stalin's predilection for killing engineers who disagreed with his 'optimistic' timeframes for the five year plan started a massive 'brain drain' by killing off all the competent, honest engineers, and leaving the sycophants who cut lots of corners. The same with the Russian army purges. Whilst Russia did eventually win the war - it cost them more than if all the competent officers had not been killed for political expediency. The same applies to their economy. user is right on the money.

Comment: +! for a good answer, but in particular the last paragraph.  As a frame challenge (which is valid for the way this question was answered) it was good to introduce that challenge in the introduction.  I'd point to this answer as a good example of *how to write a good answer.*

Answer (score 35):

One reason was that America was the biggest winner of World War II. It started the war with about 40% of the world's industrial capacity (according to Paul Kennedy, the Rise and Fall of the Great Powers"), and ended with about "half" of the capacity of a war-torn world. Other countries that were on the winning side, Britain, the Soviet Union, and China, were worse off than before the war. The war weariness was most felt in Britain, where voters threw out war leader Churchill. Many people in Britain went "left" because they did not feel that the sacrifices were worth it, or that they had gotten their fair share of the spoils.

Returning American "GI" veterans were the most empowered men in the world. The [GI Bill](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G.I._Bill) gave men from working class families the means to attend college, and later staff the managerial ranks of America's burgeoning industrial complex. Those that retained "blue" collars were still war heroes, and treated as such by unions, and managements. American workers had fewer grievances than those elsewhere, and were less likely to sympathize with "leftists."

In 1945, there were three basic political groups: liberal Democrats, conservative democrats, and (right-leaning) Republicans. Taken as a "body," the American public was quite conservative. President Franklin Delano Roosevelt was admired for his "competence," but he was actually placed in power by a conservative Texan, [John Nance Garner.](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/17340/why-didnt-henry-a-wallace-become-president-in-1945) After FDR tried to replace Garner as Vice-President with his leftist "soul mate," Henry Wallace in 1940, the Democratic Party balked in 1944 and insisted on the more conservative [Harry Truman,](http://www.goodreads.com/quotes/728071-if-we-see-that-germany-is-winning-we-ought-to) who (in)famously said, "“If we see that Germany is winning we ought to help Russia and if Russia is winning we ought to help Germany, and that way let them kill as many as possible, although I don't want to see Hitler victorious under any circumstances.” After he became President, Truman allied with (West) Germany and started the [Cold War](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cold_War)
against the Russians. This helped lead to the "villification of "left wingers" in the United States.

"The Nazis are and were demonised as much in the US" as elsewhere. That's true only up to a point. It is important to note that through the 1950s, some people in  America advocated racial policies against African-Americans that were actually "milder" versions of Nazi racial policies. Some authorities believe that Naziism was partly inspired by the [American eugenics movement](http://historynewsnetwork.org/article/1796) of the 1920s.

Comment: The GI bill seems like a set of pretty left-leaning ideas to me, and wasn't the top tax rate in the 90s right after WW2?

Comment: @Wossname: According to (Republican) authors William Strauss and Neil Howe in "Generations," the top 90% tax rate was a fiscally conservative move to pay off the war debt, and the Gi Bill was the soldiers' reward for bringing about Americas (imperialistic) "Rendezvous With Destiny." http://history.stackexchange.com/questions/15374/has-any-generation-generally-agreed-that-the-next-generation-was-better/15403#15403

Comment: I don't think that US won the WW II. In my opinion Stalin (and Communist party of USSR) won the war. Because they got rid off opposition in USSR and in all countries in eastern Europe.

Comment: @Crowley: You are right from a military perspective, the Soviet Union won the war. But from the perspective of "who got the best deal," it was America and the Americans. Or put another way, "who came away with the most."

Comment: @TomAu You didn't get my point. Communists - or Stalinists - won the war. Not the USSR nor the US. Finland, for example, was ally of Germany only for "Enemy of my enemy is my ally" reason. Part of soviet army collaborated with Wehrmacht not to fight for Nazis but to fight against Stalin. If you compare all people in whole country, the Americans won.  If you compare "elites", Communists won.

Comment: @Crowley: Yes, the Communists won in Europe and not America, which is why Europe "jutted" left, but not America.

Comment: This explain why Czechoslovakia, Poland and other eastern republics leaned totally  left. But it doesn't explain why France and Britain leaned left.

Comment: -12 (if I could) for weak, lazy analogy to the U.S. South.  It's like saying Southerners supported the Black Panthers, because they used violence to advance their racial ideas.

Comment: @Jeffiekins: Ok, took out reference to the South, and changed it to "some people"

Comment: Czechoslovakia, Poland and other eastern republics didn't "lean" left, they were invaded by the Soviet Union and not able to pursue free politics until the 90s. If the question is to make any sense at all we have to limit it to free Western Europe - not the Communist states and not the Fascist states. The US and the USSR won the war in Europe together as allies - which immediately ended once the armies met in Berlin.

Answer (score 14):

In occupied western Europe, underground communist parties took a large role in anti-nazi resistance, for which they were electorally rewarded.  Not being occupied, the war experience in the UK and the USA was very different.  Experiences in eastern Europe, where nazi terror was replaced by stalinist oppression, was different yet.

Three days from now (on 25 February), the [February strike](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/February_strike) will be exactly 75 years ago.  This was one of the major events in Nazi-occupied Netherlands.  The strike was initiated by the underground Communist party, aiming to stop the racism against the Jews.  Although it didn't last long and didn't save any Jews, it did cause major credit to the Communist party and their best-ever election result in the [first post-war elections](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dutch_general_election,_1946), when they received over 10% nationally (1937: 3.4%) and over 30% in Amsterdam, the centre of the strike and other communist-led resistance.  [Their newspaper](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Waarheid) (*De Waarheid*, or *Truth*) was very briefly the largest newspaper in The Netherlands.  The support dwindled quickly when the communist party treated harshly (such as through character assassination) anyone not following the line determined centrally (from Moscow), including communists considered war resistance heroes by many.  Not much support was left after the Communist Party supported the Soviet invasion of Hungary after the [Hungarian revolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_Revolution_of_1956), when communist support in national elections fell to 2.4%.  It didn't take any McCarthyism to severely damage the Party — the Dutch communists did it all to themselves/with "help" from Moscow¹.

Communists were very active in other elements of the resistance as well, in The Netherlands, France, and elsewhere.

---

¹<sup>The Dutch secret service did to its part by encouraging splits within the Communist party.  To what extent they contributed to the demise of the Communist party remains up for debate.</sup>

Answer (score 13):

Compared to when?

If you look at the USA politically in 1946 vs 1939 you see a very different shift than if you were to compare 1946 to 1926.

The Great Depression and the resulting New deal did push the USA further "left" (if you can call it that).

The thing to notice is that in this case, there was a clear compelling reason to do so - 25% of Americans were out of work in various portions of the 30s.  There were clear, compelling reasons in the American mainland which drove this "jut to the left."

Contrast this to post WWII. America by and large saw economy, political, and cultural aspects work in WWII and lead America to victory. While the factors you see are true, the average American in fall 1945 would have been far more likely to see and value the success of the American system - and see strength and value in leaving it untouched.

There just was not a compelling reason for the *average American* to be motivated to "push America left" as you are asking about.

Comment: There were probably a lot of folks back then that didn't have access to health care, didn't have access to higher education, were working harder for lower wages compared to workers in other countries because of a weak labor movement, or otherwise ended up in difficult situations because of the relatively weak safety net. I think the working class and lower middle class have always had a reason to move left, yet the poor in the US often vote for Republicans. All good reasons to believe that there is something else going on than "no reason for change".

Answer (score 9):

Your question operates from a very black and white view of left/right, and your mistaken assumption is that the Nazis were of the political right.

The Nazis were Nationalist Socialists and often leaned left. Their fight against the Soviets weren't because they were opposed to Communism. Remember that Hitler allied with Stalin and then double crossed him so there wasn't a lot of ideology going on there.

"Liberal Facism" by Jonah Goldberg outlines in great detail how the Nazis had more in common with traditional leftism than American conservatism.

Comment: Outlawing trade unions, banning strikes, and allying with big business has nothing to do with leaning left.

Comment: The Nazis were fervently anti-Communist and specifically anti-Bolshevist. They saw Bolshevism as part of an international Jewish conspiracy. It was their weird racial ideology that trumped everything and makes it hard to classify in how we define right/left today. Still, the Nazi ideology was dominated by extremely far right aspects.

Comment: @gerrit -- independent trade-unions and strikes were also illegal in the Soviet Union.

Comment: @Malvolio I wouldn't personally describe Stalinist Soviet Union as left-wing either.  I think the whole story of labelling historical regimes as left or right is not very fruitful.  It's not one-dimensional at all.

Comment: @gerrit -- it may not be fruitful but it is inherent in the current question.  Personally, I rank government on a single axis, but it runs from individualist to communitarian and I find that useful.

Comment: @PeskyToaster Again labeling the Nazis as "far right" again is a myth. You're right that it was hard to label but their ideology was more leftist than anything you would find associated with American conservatism, which is what most people call "right" these days. Since this thread was about the US, that's what the comparison is.

Comment: @Malvolio - That's a good point.

Comment: Well, if the criteria for "left" is "big government" (something Rand Paul would probably subscribe to), you can't be much more left than Stalin *and* Hitler. If your concept of left is more anarchist (something I would subscribe to), Rand Paul is probably much more left than Stalin  and Hitler who were extremely authoritarian.

Comment: All these comments suppose the wrong-headed idea that "right" and "left" are useful labels for political systems in the real world.  Very sad to see otherwise-intelligent people wasting their time this way.

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider -- I like to draw the axis _vertically_, so individual freedom is at the top and collective authority is at the bottom, you know, just to make it obvious which is better.

Comment: @Jeffiekins -- "useful" depends on what you are trying to achieve.  Within a single country, one that only has two or three significant parties, it might speed discussion.  Comparing governments across countries, no, I don't think it is descriptive.

Comment: @Malvolio That's [pure Reagan](https://reaganlibrary.archives.gov/archives/reference/timechoosing.html): "You and I are told increasingly we have to choose between a left or right. Well I'd like to suggest there is no such thing as a left or right. There's only an up or down—[up] man's old—old-aged dream, the ultimate in individual freedom consistent with law and order, or down to the ant heap of totalitarianism. And regardless of their sincerity, their humanitarian motives, those who would trade our freedom for security have embarked on this downward course."

Comment: @MichaelHampton -- I knew there was a reason I liked him.

Comment: During Nazi Occupation, the following was introduced in Holland: social security, workers comp., universal health care (single payer !) and environmental protection. How is that for leftist politics? The Dutch social democrats have always (successfully) defended this Nazi legacy as great social progress.

Answer (score 9):

In order to discuss this sensibly, it's necessary to distinguish the social-democrat left from the actual Communist left. "Fabian" socialism as opposed to revolutionary Marxism. The former pursued economic redistribution, the establishment of public healthcare and education systems, and nationalisation of *some* industries while generally leaving private property alone and retaining elections. The latter didn't, and were often thoroughly infiltrated by actual Stalinists and KGB agents. Although not as thoroughly as Joe McCarthy would have you believe.

Another key point is that European countries became command economies (or at least heavily requisitioned economies) as soon as the war started. Non-state economic activity became very difficult due to lack of resources and manpower, while a huge state economy was built to produce war materiel and ration everything else.

Let's also not understate how much was destroyed, and how many people were killed, exiled, expropriated, wounded or seriously inconvenienced by the war. It was a war of indiscriminate destruction from the air. A significant fraction of Europe's remaining traditional hereditary aristocracy were killed, in some cases wiping out entire family lines.

The existing social and economic order was simply blown to pieces, a lot needed to be (re)built, and everyone was already mobilised. It's a short step from state-directed building of aircraft, hospitals and barracks to state-directed building of cars, hospitals and houses.

America suffered no such destruction of property, providing less of an opportunity to redistribute its replacement. Meanwhile the foundations for post-war technological industries were being built around the arms manufacturers, and the post-war space race.

There were a lot of public left/right confrontations in various countries in the 60s. Everything from the US civil rights movement to the soixante-huitards to the Greek internal conflict which collapsed into a military dictatorship. Italy could have gone either way (and the CIA were involved there, in Operation Gladio). Also de-colonialisation by France and the UK; arguably this is a shift to the "left".

It's also important to look at how pivotal individual figures were and how differently things could have gone if, say, JFK and MLK hadn't been assasinated. The US *could* have ended up not so far to the right.

But ultimately a lot of the US "rightism" was straightforward power politics of anti-communism, competing against the Soviet Union. This included sponsoring terrorism and coups in South America, the Vietnam War, and so on.

**Edit**: this is a *huge* question, really. How much of "Europe" are you counting? France+Benelux+West Germany+Scandinavia+Italy count as "left", I suppose, but what about military dictatorships in Spain+Portugal+Greece?

About bomb damage in the UK: while this only affected a small fraction of buildings, it was an omnipresent *threat* in any urban area. The British victory is seen in popular history as fundamentally collective - "pulling together", "blitz spirit", Dunkirk's "little ships", rationing, etc. (Slightly contradicted by talking about "the few" of the air superiority fighters and the aristocratic flavour of the RAF, though).

America lacks universal health care partly because of a persistent popular belieft that ill-health reflects immorality, while the UK set its up at a time (1944) when anyone could be injured by shrapnel at any time without it being a reflection on their character.

Comment: Good answer; the only thing is: England was not damaged nearly as badly as the Continent, and yet it, too, leaned more to the left after the War. And on the Continent certain countries were less badly impacted that also leaned left, if I remember correctly. I do think the direct impact of the War has something to do with it, since England is now in some ways also pretty right-wing compared to the Continent; but there is more to it. The Frontier mentality mentioned earlier is important; but then again, why was America in some ways more leftist than Europe shortly before the War? The colonies?

Comment: "why was America in some ways more leftist than Europe shortly before the War" - in what way?

Answer (score 6):

This is a great question, and I've decided to write my own answer since the existing ones fail to mention a few facts.

1. Reason #1 should be J. Edgar Hoover. Even before Truman's creating the 'national security state', the FBI succeeded in infiltrating the communist party and most left-wing organizations. Out of each four communist party card-carrying members, three were FBI informants. The 'left' field was completely and utterly compromised.
2. The unions, unlike their European counterparts, were averse to communist propaganda. Some union leaders used to be '[fellow travelers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fellow_traveler)' in the 1930s but the purges, the Winter War, and the Molotow-Ribbentrop Pact quickly changed their minds (cf. the case of [Walter Reuther](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Walter_Reuther) who was instrumental in getting rid of pink colors in the UAW membership). The unions were quite influential, and members of the **New Deal coalition**.
3. Harry Truman gathered various conservative, wealthy, East Coast-educated, Georgetown-dining gentlemen in the national security apparatus. This machine worked efficiently to protect itself and the American state from subversion, i.a. by allying with and indirectly controlling mainstream media outlets (see the [Alsop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stewart_Alsop) [brothers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joseph_Alsop), for instance). It also expended much effort and money to subvert European communist parties, to set up 'stay behind' shadow state, to train law enforcement and special services there...
4. Stalin had his hands full and naturally devoted more attention to the events in Europe.
5. The United States quickly climbed out of shallow post-war economic depression and surged forward. Whatever rationing there was was quickly abolished. *A full belly would not harbor treasonous thoughts*.

Answer (score 3):

The main difference between the totalitarian states in the 1900s and the democracies was not at all in economic policy but in to what extent and to what detail the (federal) state was allowed to rule over citizens (private) lives by using force.

The bipolar left-right economical spectrum did not at all take authoritarian / personal liberty into account.

"Extreme left" and "extreme right" did not mean extremely much to the left or extremely much to the right. It meant "economically left But with extremely little personal freedom" and "economically right But with extremely little personal freedom".

Answer (score 0):

The share of government spending in GDP is mainly correlated with growth of the service sector and urbanization. In agrarian societies, people are independent and can live off the land. As countries develop people become more dependent on government.

In the US urbanization was a bit slower, hence, the slower spending growth.

Comment: What does this have to do with "left/right" politics?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://history.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://history.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/23022)

Comment: @PieterGeerkens (and at curious) But it does! Mustang contends that  big government "left" politics boost the service sector which is tied to (and benefits) urban centers;  the US, lagging in urbanization compared to the West European countries experiencing the left swing, therefore didn't have as much clientele to perform a left swing.-- But I doubt that it's historically correct that the US was less industrialized/urbanized than West Europe.

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider In the US there was and still is large amount of "free land" and the density of population is far lower in the US compared to Europe.

Comment: @PeterG The social/economic features associated with leftwing politics all correlate with urbanization. Urban/rural voting patterns are a major feature of political science.

Comment: @Crowley The amount of "free land" or the overall population density is largely irrelevant to the discussion. The interesting question is what the proportion of urban vs. rural population was, as a first rough measure of how many people would (allegedly) profit from big gov. In 1950 for the US it's 64/100 urban (https://www.census.gov/population/censusdata/urpop0090.txt); in Germany 68/100 (http://www.geohive.com/earth/pop_urban2.aspx). That would support Mustang.

Comment: @Peter A. Schneider: But is a difference of 4% really enough to affect voting outcomes?  A greater effect may come from the way the US Senate is elected: two Senators from each state, regardless of population, giving rural areas more influence.

Comment: Both matter. Urbanization is not a binary concept, there are levels of urbanization. Plus, the question is about the huge electoral swing in the UK, which was significantly more urbanized than the US or Germany at the time (79%). http://www.theguardian.com/news/datablog/2009/aug/18/percentage-population-living-cities

Comment: Also, Germany pursued "ordoliberalism" after the war and did not swing as far to the left as northern european urbanized countries.

Comment: @Mustang "Germany not as far left": Mostly true (talking west germany), but only after a few years. The immediate post war period saw a strong socialist movement also in West Germany. The Social Democrats, one of the two big parties, were "true socialists", opposing capitalism. But after a few years they moved to the center, reflecting the general success, materially and ideologically, of the capitalist *wirtschaftswunder*.

Comment: The social democrats never suceeeded in enacting significant spending increases or leftwing policies postwar. In fact the SPD hardly ever held office until 66, and when it did held office, it was mostly in urban areas.

Comment: Meanwhile in 1917 Russia had a Communist far left revolution as an agrarian feudal society; I think this is an oversimplification.

Comment: Also the base of Bolshevik power was in the cities and they had a hard time wininning over the countryside (which they basically gave up and chose to ethnically cleanse agricultural areas instead).

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to read all of the comments above - but am sure someone has mentioned the dichotomy between statism and anarchy/libertarianism. Global governments desired more control post-WWII (including the United States) but the people were oftentimes more inclined to give it in affluent Europe or nations undergoing an industrial revolution such as those in Central or South America.

Many in the U.S., at least identify with the idea of limited government more than their European counterparts - certainly in regards to economics. We've seen this play out significantly over the past 50 years.

Answer (score -1):

There was a lot of left in America during those years. I'm skipping some countries, but I'm sure you can read something about the left in America over [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_Latin_America) and [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latin_America_during_World_War_II).

*Edit: Question title changed, answer no more valid. Thanks for correcting!*

Comment: ooh you're getting downvoted for daring to include Latin America into America.